# AttributeError-module 'urllib.request' has no attribute 'META'

Tags: python, django, django-views

i just started django
here is my view

```
from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from urllib import request
    def homepage(*args,**kwargs):
        return render(request,'home.html')
    # Create your views here.
    def requestpage(*args,**kwargs):
        return render(request,'req.html')
```

which gives[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Uuw.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should *not* import `request`, `request` is the first parameter of the view, so:

```
def homepage(request, *args,**kwargs):
    return render(request,'home.html')

def requestpage(request, *args,**kwargs):
    return render(request,'req.html')
```